# Minecraft NPC Paths

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using Dragnoz's NPC Paths:

But if I have two paths run along each other, the villagers will occasionally push each other off, or if it becomes night time or there is a zombie, the villager will try to run away, off the path.  Is there anyway around this?  I would rather not use NoAI:1 unless I have to.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that is not readily apparent given your question is why you want your Villagers not to be afraid of Zombies. If they're not afraid, they'll just die; but I assume you don't care because you're trying to create some sort of escort quest.

Using the downward Motion should cause the Villagers to be "unbumpable." I watched this video fairly recently and if you just set the Y value of the Motion array to -0.1 it ought to be okay. If crossing paths is a problem, just do something like

```
/scoreboard objectives add path1
/scoreboard objectives add path2
// etc.
```

I don't see any way around NoAI unless you want to do something weird like make them ride an ArmorStand and move that around, which could look awful.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the long wait. I tried the -0.1 method but when they are standing directly on the stairs they would usually fall down into the block around turns. And if I changed it so that it detected them 1 block above the stairs, they would always fall down into that block. On a brighter note, I found that using NoAI is perfect for what I was trying to do. I hadn't actually used NoAI until now, and thought the villagers wouldn't walk/look the way they were moving. I'll still have to find a way to stop the bumping. Thanks for the help, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a wall two blocks high, or more if you want, along the edges of the path. I would prefer cobblestone, if you are building it around lava or fire. Do NOT use gravel or sand if you are building it in mid-air. If this is not the answer you were looking for, I apologize.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work. I tried using barriers, but the villagers were being teleported to close to the wall, and took damage from it. Plus, I would like the player to be able to go through the path on the villager. I will probably end up using NoAI or something like that.

Comment: Oops! Can you make the path wider, or would that be messing it up?

Comment: I can make the paths wider, but that would mean other villagers would also run along that path, pushing other villagers off, unless I make it so that only certain professions would run along that path. That might work.

Answer (score 0):

NoAI would be required, but what you could do is give the villagers a certain score, determining their direction. Every cycle you would teleport the villagers forward based on that score. If a villager stands 2 blocks above a stair, it's score would be changed to the direction of the stair. Then only place stairs in the corners of their paths.